# Problem redirecting to 10.0.2.2 when using Facebook OAuth with Android Emulator

Tags: android, facebook, xamarin, oauth, android-emulator

I have a Xamarin.Forms app targeting Android and iOS communicating with an ASP.NET Core backend. I need to implement social authentication for the app - Facebook and Google for now. Following [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/authentication-xamarin-essentials-aspnet/) Microsoft guide I added Xamarin.Essentials.WebAuthenticator in my mobile app, created the appropriate authentication endpoints and added Facebook auth middleware.
Now my problem is that I'm using an Android emulator for development and in order for me to communicate with my server backend (hosted on my developer machine) I need to use the special IP address 10.0.2.2 as described [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking).  The problem is that in order for the OAuth workflow to work I need to list 10.0.2.2 as a Valid redirect URL in the Facebook developer portal.

The problem with this is that I get an which says that "This can't be a Facebook URL" which means that the URL is not whitelisted. That means that whenever I try to authenticate through the Android emulator using the 10.0.2.2:44351 address to refer to my backend, I get error from Facebook saying that "This URL is not whitelisted under "Valid OAuth Redirect URIs".

How can I work around this?

Comment: I don’t think you can work around this from the Facebook side. Because this is a local IP address, they identify this as a “Facebook URL”, and there is no way to circumvent that validation. Plus, Facebook login doesn’t work properly with IP addresses to begin with, it pretty much _needs_ to be done via a hostname.

Comment: @CBroe I see, so how can I make the auth workflow succeed from the emulator?

Comment: I don’t know if you can. If the emulator does not allow to access this using any other way than via this local IP … then you might need to find a different way to test altogether.